# iOS 11 PDFKit Ink annotation - cannot fill UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, ipad, uibezierpath, pdfkit

I'm adding ink annotations to PDFDocument using the PDFAnnotation() class with subtype ink. The idea is to capture signatures that are drawn using touch.

Inspired by UberSignature my UIBezierPath is a series of rectangles that are supposed to be filled with a color. However, when I add the annotation to the PDFDocument it is not filled.

It seems the UIBezierPath's fill() method does nothing at all when added to a PDFAnnotation?

If I use the same UIBezierPath and draw it on an UIImage it is correctly filled with a solid color.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Problematic code:

```
UIColor.red.setStroke()
UIColor.red.setFill()

var path = UIBezierPath()
path.append(myRectangles)
path.fill()

var annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: path.bounds, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
annotation.add(path)
myPDFPage.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

[image: Current view of PDF]

In the screenshot I have tried to write normal text, and two example lines. The line on the left is drawn slowly, the line on the right is drawn fast. The idea is to have width of the line vary according to the speed it is drawn to make a signature look more natural/realistic.

Comment: Have you found a way to adjust lines width and style depending on Pencil's pressure, speed and position? I tried to implement the same way as Apple uses in their sample app (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/leveraging_touch_input_for_drawing_apps), but faced serious performance issues.

Comment: Yes, I use the technique displayed in my question and answer, where I add "chop up" the line into a number of smaller quadrilaterals of different sizes. To improve performance I make sure to make several annotations instead of bunching everything into one, and I have also implemented bitmap caching. I.e. I store the actual bitmap calculated for every x iterations, so that when strokes are added, I only have to render the newest strokes on each draw. The rest is cached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to the problem that seems relatively optimal.

The trick is do create a subclass of PDFAnnotation and override the draw(with box:, in context:) function. In this function I can use the drawPath(using: .fill) method to fill out bezier path.

The code can look like this:

```
class SignatureAnnotation : PDFAnnotation {
  public var myPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()

  override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
    context.saveGState()
    self.page?.transform(context, for: box)
    context.beginPath()
    context.setLineWidth(0.1)
    context.setShouldAntialias(true)
    context.addPath(self.myPath.cgPath.mutableCopy()!)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    context.restoreGState()
  }
}
```

Add this annotation (type .stamp) to the PDF instead of the ink annotation, and everything will be rendered as vector (fully zoomable without being pixelated) - and will be saved together with the rest of the PDF when saved to file or data buffer.

Only drawback is that the UIBezierPath cannot be too complicated as flickering will be introduced if the draw() function takes too long. This can be solved by simply splitting up the UIBezierPath into multiple seperate paths that each has its own annotation.

Comment: Is this annotation visible in other PDF rendering applications? Can it be manipulated like annotation (move, change size, copy, paste)?

Comment: Yes, visible in other PDF rendering applications (I have tested with Apple Preview and the built-in Google Chrome PDF viewer). I'm not interested in manipulating the annotations afterwards, so I haven't tried that.

Comment: Hey could you please upload a sample code how you achieved this? Would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @jksoegaard Thank you for sharing this. Tried to implement your solution in my project and I can only draw the first segment of UIBezierPath while others are not being drawn. Could you, please, share some more pieces of your code?

Comment: Have you tried checking your UIBezierPath in the debugger to check that there are actually multiple segments?  - Works without problems for me.

Comment: @jksoegaard Seems, I found my issues:
1. Was unable to make your code working, so found that solution in one of Apple's sample codes:
`class DrawingAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {
    public var path = UIBezierPath()
    
    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        context.saveGState()
        UIColor.red.set()
        path.fill()
        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}`
Still not found working solution for changing line width.

Comment: @jksoegaard 2. Second issue is forcing PDFAnnotation to redraw itself. I tried to create one annotation [in touchesBegan] and edit path when touch continues. However, the only solution I found is to call addAnnotation/removeAnnotation.

Comment: The code works fine in my app. Changing line width is not simple - there’s no property for that. My solution was to draw to parallel paths with line connecting them, and then fill that. Quite complicated, but allows the line width to change along the path.

Answer (score 1):

InkAnnotation is rendered as a collection of stroked paths. There is no way to fill it with colour according to [PDF reference 1.4 page 508](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/PDFReference.pdf).

Apple's Preview uses Stamp annotation to include signature to PDFs. I tried to use PDFKit to reverse engineer it but I cannot see any vector data that would contain the signature I placed in the PDF. PDFKit may be not sufficient here.

```
(lldb) po annotation.annotationKeyValues
▿ 10 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/AAPL:Hash")
      - value : "/AAPL:Hash"
    - value : /264236ab9aaabfe2d536167a89c26c2d
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/DA")
      - value : "/DA"
    - value : /Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/T")
      - value : "/T"
    - value : Wojciech Nagrodzki
  ▿ 3 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/F")
      - value : "/F"
    - value : 4
  ▿ 4 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/Subtype")
      - value : "/Subtype"
    - value : /Stamp
  ▿ 5 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/Name")
      - value : "/Name"
    - value : /Draft
  ▿ 6 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/Rect")
      - value : "/Rect"
    - value : NSRect: {{5.8745389999999995, 748.38995}, {307.66119599999996, 87.648936000000049}}
  ▿ 7 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/Border")
      - value : "/Border"
    - value : PDFBorder: {solid lineWidth:2.8 hCorner:0.0 vCorner:0.0 dashCount:0 dashPattern:(
)}
  ▿ 8 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/Type")
      - value : "/Type"
    - value : /Annot
  ▿ 9 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("/C")
      - value : "/C"
    - value : kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1
```

The `fill()` method you is used to fill path in current graphic context, this is not related to annotations.

If using stamp annotation fails you could also render the path in graphic context, convert it to image and place in the PDF. But I am not sure if you take this under consideration at all.

You can find more PDF references in the [Adobe's archives](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html).

Comment: Sadly none of these really solve the problem. An image would be suboptimal as it would be pixelated when zoomed in, contrary to the vector format of the ink annotation. Also adding the image inside the PDF is problematic as PDFKit actually don't have any mechanisms for altering the contents of the PDF - only annotations. In the mean time I actually solved the problem the other day - adding an answer now with the specifics.